# scrape website through it's api using request

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to scrape live matches data from this website: https://egamersworld.com/matches

I tried using the api: https://api.egamersworld.com/matches?lang=en
but ruturn nothing:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
url = "https://api.egamersworld.com/matches?lang=en"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0', "referer": "https://egamersworld.com/"}

r = session.get(url, timeout=30, headers=headers)     
print(r.status_code) #200
r.json() #{"list":[]}
```

`r.status_code` return 200, but the `r.json()` return nothing.
How I can get the data using this api ?

Answer (score 2):

I could not see that API endpoint being accessed from that page, however, there are a couple different ones, and here is one way of getting the data from one of them:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'x-customheader': '435b8c763ab097da9947a385cfe127b0',
    'origin': 'https://egamersworld.com',
    'referer': 'https://egamersworld.com/',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://api.egamersworld.com/live_events?lang=en'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json())
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    _id     tags    title   game    slug    prize   start_date  finish_date     prize_num   image   is_live
0   Nkqg6l-SR   [{'title': 'LPL', 'slug': 'lpl'}]   LPL Summer 2023     lol     lpl-2023-summer-Nkqg6l-SR   $597,366    2023-05-28T23:00:00.000Z    2023-08-07T23:00:00.000Z    597366  /uploads/tournaments/lpl-summer-20231685005813...   True
1   4kxt3zcXVa  [{'title': 'ESL', 'slug': 'esl'}, {'title': 'I...   IEM Dallas 2023     counterstrike   iem-dallas-2023-4kxt3zcXVa  $250,000    2023-05-29T00:00:00.000Z    2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z    250000  /uploads/tournaments/intel-extreme-masters-dal...   True
2   NyVSQFNp3   [{'title': 'DPC', 'slug': 'dpc'}]   DPC 2023 Tour 3: CN Division I (Upper)  dota2   dpc-2022-2023-tour-3-season-3-china-division-i...   $205,000    2023-05-16T00:00:00.000Z    2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z    205000  /uploads/tournaments/dpc-2022-2023-summer-tour...   True
3   V1u4WtNT2   [{'title': 'DPC', 'slug': 'dpc'}]   DPC 2023 Tour 3: NA Division I (Upper)  dota2   dpc-2022-2023-tour-3-season-3-na-division-i-up...   $205,000    2023-05-15T00:00:00.000Z    2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z    205000  /uploads/tournaments/dpc-2022-2023-summer-tour...   True
4   VJvpbYN6h   [{'title': 'DPC', 'slug': 'dpc'}]   DPC 2023 Tour 3: SA Division I (Upper)  dota2   dpc-2022-2023-tour-3-season-3-sa-division-i-up...   $205,000    2023-05-15T00:00:00.000Z    2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z    205000  /uploads/tournaments/dpc-2022-2023-summer-tour...   True
5   4ymHMF4Tn   [{'title': 'DPC', 'slug': 'dpc'}]   DPC 2023 Tour 3: WEU Division I (Upper)     dota2   dpc-2022-2023-tour-3-season-3-weu-division-i-u...   $205,000    2023-05-15T00:00:00.000Z    2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z    205000  /uploads/tournaments/dpc-2022-2023-summer-tour...   True
6   N1hQNtNp2   [{'title': 'DPC', 'slug': 'dpc'}]   DPC 2023 Tour 3: SEA Division I (Upper)     dota2   dpc-2022-2023-tour-3-season-3-sea-division-i-u...   $205,000    2023-05-15T00:00:00.000Z    2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z    205000  /uploads/tournaments/dpc-2022-2023-summer-tour...   True
7   4JtpGFET2   [{'title': 'DPC', 'slug': 'dpc'}]   DPC 2023 Tour 3: EEU Division I (Upper)     dota2   dpc-2022-2023-tour-3-season-3-eeu-division-i-u...   $205,000    2023-05-14T00:00:00.000Z    2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z    205000  /uploads/tournaments/dpc-2022-2023-summer-tour...   True
8   41twsuwVC   [{'title': 'Champion of Champions Tour', 'slug...   CCT 2023 Online Finals 1    counterstrike   cct-2023-online-finals-1-41twsuwVC  $200,000    2023-05-23T00:00:00.000Z    2023-05-30T00:00:00.000Z    200000  /uploads/tournaments/cct-2023-online-finals-11...   True
9   N174ae0_0   []  Europe League 2023 - Stage 2    rainbowsix  europe-league-2023-stage-2-N174ae0_0    $191,049    2023-05-01T23:00:00.000Z    2023-05-30T23:00:00.000Z    191049  /uploads/tournaments/europe-league-2023-stage-...   True
```

Page is also being hydrated with info from a couple of websockets connections. Here is one way of getting that streaming information:

```
import websocket

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code,close_msg):
    print("closed connection")

socket = 'wss://ws.egamersworld.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket'
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket,on_message= on_message, on_close=on_close)

ws.run_forever()
```

Response in terminal:

```
0{"sid":"fVEBxmYMAFO-RAPoCQtq","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000}
40
42["cs",{"NkKs8f2rA":{"mapStat":{"homeTeam":[{"steamId":"1:1:73849600","dbId":19996,"name":"Jelo","score":17,"deaths":9,"assists":0,"alive":false,"money":56500,"damagePrRound":802,"hp":0,"kevlar":false,"helmet":false,"nick":"Jelo","hasDefusekit":false,"advancedStats":{"kast":1,"entryKills":0,"entryDeaths":0,"multiKillRounds":1,"oneOnXWins":0,"flashAssists":0}},{"steamId":"1:1:571082935","dbId":22703,"name":"moonwalk","score":8,"deaths":10,"assists":0,"alive":false,"money":43200,"damagePrRound":369,"hp":0,"kevlar":false,"helmet":false,"nick":"moonwalk","hasDefusekit":false,"advancedStats":{"kast":1,"entryKills":0,"entryDeaths":0,"multiKillRounds":1,"oneOnXWins":0,"flashAssists":.....
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to scrape live scores, the url on your answer don't give the data I need

Comment: @khaledkoubaa Funny enough, the API endpoint I indicated contains `live_events`... nonetheless,  you may be looking for the info streamed from web-sockets. Check the updated answer. Good luck.

Comment: thanks, may I know from where you find the link ```'wss://ws.egamersworld.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket'``` so I can do it by myself (find id) in other similar projects ? I mean how to find such link

Comment: In Chrome tools, under Network - WS.

Comment: thanks, I found it. how I can store the data from the infinite runned socket ? I want to create dataframe from the results